# After saying something

Tags: sentence-construction

Do these have the same meaning? What would be the best version in your opinion?

- After saying something, I sit, look at the water and drink it using my right hand in three breaths to quench my thirst.
- After saying something, I look at the water and drink it using my right hand in three breaths to quench my thirst while sitting (down) .
- After saying something and looking at the water, I drink it using my right hand in three breaths to quench my thirst while sitting (down).
- After saying something, I sit and use my right hand to drink water to quench my thirst, stopping 3 times to take a breath and look at it (OR and look at the water).

NB: The reason of using "in three breaths" is that I am pausing three times to take breath while drinking water. Is there any better phrase that I can use instead of it for sounding more natural?

Comment: This question seems more about writing style than learning English, and so it would be more appropriate to a writing clinic than and English learner's website. As is, this will never be relevant to any other user of the site. Is there a specific grammar issue or vocabulary choice you're asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to say what you are trying to get across is:

> After saying something, I sit, look at the water, and using my right hand, drink it, pausing three times to take a breath.

I don't know how you can fit the part about quenching your thirst in that single sentence without it being unwieldy. In fact, it's already a bit of a mouthful and it's probably not the way a native speaker would tell that story. For example, unless using your right hand is important, you can leave that out entirely.

It's best to break it into several sentences. For example:

> I finish speaking and sit. Thirstily, I look at the glass of water in front of me and move to drink it, pausing only three times to take single breaths. I set the emptied glass down on the table, my thirst quenched.

Now, this is more of a literary way of saying it than how you would say it in conversation. I only made it to illustrate that you can break your idea into smaller chunks and have it sound pretty good and be easy to follow.

To answer your other questions:

> After saying something, I look at the water and drink it using my right hand in three breaths to quench my thirst while sitting (down)

This implies you were already sitting down while you drank. Your first sentence, which I didn't quote, shows that you sat after you finished speaking.

> After saying something and looking at the water, I drink it using my right hand in three breaths to quench my thirst while sitting (down)

This has an identical meaning to the above.

> After saying something, I sit and use my right hand to drink water to quench my thirst, stopping 3 times to take a breath and look at it (OR and look at the water)

This has effectively the same meaning as your first sentence, except by saying "stopping 3 times" instead of "in three breaths", it seems to imply that it took a bit longer. I don't think the difference is all that meaningful, as the underlying meaning remains the same.